# How can I start a while loop in PineScript when the price has fallen below a certain level and stop it when it has risen above a higher level?

Tags: loops, while-loop, pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I would like to define the following with a while loop.
After falling below a certain price level a loop is started. It ends only when a higher price level is exceeded again. When the loop ends, it should output a value that I can then continue to work with.

For example

a = 0

If the SPX falls below 4000, the loop starts.
Only when the SPX then rises again above 4200, the loop stops and changes a := 1

Then I know when a = 1, the scenario has occurred and can take further action based on that.

Can someone give me an example, that shows how to define that?

Comment: Why do you need a while loop if all you need is to find out if the price has fallen below 4000 and risen above 4200?

Comment: I haven't figured out another way, with which I can make sure that two conditions are met one after the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Revised Answer:**

The solution is simply to iterate through each previous bar to check for the fallenBelow condition being withing a certain range of the risenAbove condition using a while loop that looks like this:

```js
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © lysergik

//@version=5
indicator("backAboveDectector")

bool belowThenAboveInRange = false // this becomes true when your condition is met

// Inputs
float priceLevel = input.float(23700)
int lookback = input.int(10, 'lookback')

// Logic

bool fallenBelow = close[1] >= priceLevel and close < priceLevel
bool risenAbove = close[1] <= priceLevel and close > priceLevel

i = 1
while belowThenAboveInRange == false and i <= lookback
    if risenAbove[0] and fallenBelow[i]
        belowThenAboveInRange := true
    else
        i += 1

// front-end

plotshape(belowThenAboveInRange ? 0 : na, style=shape.diamond, location=location.absolute)
```

The trick to get a boolean of risenAbove but only when fallenBelow was true within a specified range prior is to use a while loop to look through the previous bars.

The loop checks for the current candle being analyzed by the script for the risenAbove condition and then checks the previous bar for the fallenBelow condition. If it did not fall below on that prior candle, it will add 1 to `i` and repeat the check until either both conditions are met or the iteration limit is hit.

**Notes:**

- There must be a limit (although it can be quite large) because the script is run on every single bar in visible range and therefore Pinescript limits the script to take maximum 500ms to compute.
- If you only want your condition to be true when the level is risen-above the very next bar after falling-below, then you can omit the while loop altogether and just run the check once; replacing `i` with '1'

[image: example of solution working]

**Additional Example**

You can define two different levels for `fallenBelow` and `risenAbove` like this, where `float1` is the threshold for falling below ('starting the loop') and `float2` is the threshold it must rise above afterwards:

*Uncorrelated; unrelated and individually mutable*

```js
bool fallenBelow = close[1] >= [float1] and close < [float1]
bool risenAbove = close[1] <= [float2] and close > [float2]
```

*Correlated; float2 is in this example always 5% higher than float1*

```js
bool fallenBelow = close[1] >= [float1] and close < [float1]
bool risenAbove = close[1] <= [float1*1.05] and close > [float1*1.05]
```

Comment: I will try again to describe in detail what I am about: 
I want a point to be marked in my chart, for example with plotshape, when two prices have been reached in a row. Let's take the spread USOIL-UKOIL 
Every time the spread dropped below -10 and then rebounded to >-7, I want the -7 spot to be marked on the chart. This level of -7 is only interesting if the price was <-10 before. This is to show when there was initially an exaggeration of the spread below a certain level, but then the rebound takes place again. 
It does not have to be done with while.

Comment: I have your solution. I'm going to edit your question based on your comment here and edit my response so this post can be useful to viewers besides us.

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful reply. 
I have two follow-up questions. 
Can I also define different levels? 
One for the level that must be fallen below and one for the level that must be exceeded again?
Based on your example that the price must first fall below 23700 and then rise back above 25000 for the condition to be met?

And can I specify priceLevel with the value of a moving average of a fixed symbol?
So that for example it is specified that if the MA5 of the SPX has fallen below a certain level and then risen above it again, the condition is true?

Comment: You're welcome! And yes, you need only to define two separate levels as variables in any way you want. Then simply change the booleans risenAbove / fallenBelow to reference each their own respective level instead of both referencing the same variable/level. And you can replace 'close' with a variable that == ta.sma(close,n) if you want to look at moving averages instead. Cheers.

Comment: I'm sorry to write again, but I couldn't get it to work even with your clear instructions. Would you be so kind and code me a short example with two separate levels for fallenBelow and risenAbove? That would be super helpful:)

Comment: updated my answer to include examples of how the levels can be different and either related or not. If this works for you please don't forget to accept the answer; thanks!